# Will this texture sharing technique work in my universal iOS app?

Tags: ios, textures, universal, retina-display

I'm creating an universal iOS game and I'm trying to come up with a good system to share textures. In my case, all the retina iPhone textures are exactly the same size as my iPad textures. Right now I have separate directories for iPad and iPhone content which is very redundant. I would also like to have iPad3 content in my project.

My idea is to have three different versions for every texture:

```
texture - non-retina iPhone
texture@2x - retina iPhone / non-retina iPad
texture@2x@2x - retina iPad
```

When the iPhone wants to load a texture, I would point it to the base texture. When the iPad wants to load a texture I would just append an @2x to it. Would this scheme also allow the iPad 3 to find the texture@2x@2x?

Comment: I don't think Apple discourages universal builds, it is documented as 'preferred'. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AppDesignBasics/AppDesignBasics.html

Answer (score 0):

you dont need a separate graphic for the iPad retina and the iPhone retina they are both @2x

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I'm aware that both the iPad retina and iPhone retina need an @2x. In my case, I want the iPad to load the iPhone's retina image. This will save me so much space since they are exactly the same file. My concern is, can I tell the iPad to load that file, and will the iPad 3 find the @2x@2x file.

Comment: sorry I think I did misunderstand, but I dont think your scheme will work with the @2x@2x.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this technique out and it worked totally fine. I don't have an iPad 3 to directly test if texture@2x@2x will work. However, I took a non-retina image and called it image@2x. Then I made a retina version and called that image@2x@2x. The iPhone 4 loaded the @2x@2x version thinking it was retina and everything was fine. I assume the iPad 3 can do the same thing without a problem. My universal app's size was reduced from 44MB to 29MB by sharing all the redundant content!